# Do mass updates lock up a table?

Tags: mysql, database

From what I've seen, mass delete and inserts lock up a table.
Would mass update cause the same problem? I thank you in advance.

Comment: We have both ISAM and Innodb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your question depends on the storage engine used by the table in question.

If your table is backed by [MyISAM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/myisam-storage-engine.html), the entire table will be locked for the duration of the update. On the other hand, if you're using [Innodb](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-storage-engine.html), only the rows scanned along with gaps in the index will be locked. You're free to read/write from/to other rows.

See

- [The InnoDB Transaction Model and Locking](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-transaction-model.html)
- [InnoDB Lock Modes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-lock-modes.html)
- [Internal Locking Methods](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/internal-locking.html)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the engine, yes. [see for info](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html)